Visual Studio Error E1696: cannot find intellisense source file
I am on Windows 11 and using Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.11.0 with a C++ code made of multiple .cpp and .h files. The code compiles correctly, but Intellisense does not work, and I get the Intellisense error message when building
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "C:\MAC\HOME\DOCUMENTS\MY_CODE\SRC\BODY.CPP"    minimal     0       

Where should I include the source directory
C:\MAC\HOME\DOCUMENTS\MY_CODE\SRC

so that Intellisense can find it ? I have already included that directory in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Source Directories.
Thank you

If you have added your source files to the project correctly you shouldn't have to do anything.

The old-school fix to mysterious VS errors is to delete all the settings and caches, which are in the ".vs" folder these days (I think).

First remove that entry from the 'Source Directories' settings, that is not necessary and is not the solution to this problem. Second Intellisense often gets confused, close Visual Studio and delete the .vs folder in your project folder. Third (optional) disable intellisense.

Hi @Louise, did you enable case-sensitive on your folders in C driver?

@molbdnilo I don't see any .vs folder, where is it ?

@Louise It's usually in the root of the project folder.

Are you using WSL in your machine?
If yes, this issue  could be  caused by case-sensitive folder names. Intellisense was trying to open "C:\MAC\HOME\DOCUMENTS\MY_CODE\SRC\BODY.CPP" (all uppercase) and was reporting " E1696   cannot open source file". But if C:\MAC (or any of the other directories in the path) are set to be case-sensitive and don't exactly match, it won't be found.
In this case, please disable case-sensitive for your C folder.
fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo <directory> disable

Besides, you can also try to delete  the .vs folder and rebuild your project to see if the issue persists.

It does not work: > fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo C:\Mac\Home\Documents\my_code\src\my_app.cpp disable Error:  The parameter is incorrect.

The parameter is .Please run > fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo C:\Mac\Home\Documents\my_code\src disable
